# I need help changing the integer value of ace in blackjack if the total sum is going to be higher then 21, C

Tags: c, blackjack

In my blackjack game the integer value of ace is fixed to 11 but in those cases when one player gets an ace but the total value of the cards in her hand is going to be higher then 21 I want the integer value of ace to be 1.

```
void deal(const Card * const Deck, int value, int size, int size_1, int size_2){

int i, j, length;
char anotherCard[2];
char name1[30];
char name2[30];
int valueName1 = 0, valueName2 = 0, valueDealer = 0;

printf("Name player one > ");
scanf("%s", name1);
printf("Name player two > ");
scanf("%s", name2);

printf("\nWelcome %s and %s, lets begin!\n\n", name1, name2);
getchar();

while (valueName1 < 21 || valueName2 < 21 || valueDealer < 17){
    printf("%s's card:\n", name1);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%5s of %-8s%c", Deck[i].decks, Deck[i].suits, (i + 1) % 2 ? '\t' : '\n');


    if (valueName1 > 21 && Deck[i].value == 11){
        Deck[i].value = 1;                          //error on this line
        valueName1 += Deck[i].value;
        printf("value > %d\n", valueName1);
        }
    else{
        printf("value > %d\n", valueName1);
        }
    }


int main(void){

Card allCards[52];
Card cardValue[52];
char *suitname[] = { "spades", "hearts", "diamonds", "clubs" };
char *deckname[] = { "ace", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king" };
int cardvalue[] = { 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10 };



void fillDeck(Card * const Deck, const char *suit[], const char *deck[], const int value[]){

int s;

for (s = 0; s < 52; s++){
    Deck[s].suits = deck[s % 13];
    Deck[s].decks = suit[s / 13];
    Deck[s].value = value[s % 13];
}

return;
}
```

my struct:

```
typedef struct card{
    const char *suits;
    const char *decks;
    int value;
};
```

error message:
error C2166: l-value specifies const object

Comment: Have you declared `value` with `const` modifier in your `struct`?

Comment: I think we need a bit more code to help. It looks like Deck[] may be defined with the {x,y,z...} method but it's hard to tell with what you gave us. Include the definitions for valueName1 and Deck please.

Comment: When posting question about errors, please include the complete and unedited error output in the body of the message, then just mark out the line the error is on. And always provide context, like variable and function declarations, preferably create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, with the errors from that MCVE.

Comment: In blackjack programs it's ALWAYS easier to treat the ace this way: Aces are valued as one. Period. When adding up a hand, total the values, then make a simple check: if the hand both (a) contains at least one ace, and (b) totals < 12, then add 10 to the hand and call it "soft".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `Deck` as

```
const Card * const Deck
```

That means `Deck` is a constant pointer to constant data, i.e. you can't change the pointer and (more importantly) you can't change the data it points to. You need to drop the first `const` to make it work

```
Card * const Deck
```

Comment: I think this was pointed out the 2nd time (of 4) that OP asked a Q about his project.